# How can I exchange reputation between Russian and English Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have two accounts: on Stack Overflow and on Stack Overflow на русском. On Stack Overflow I have only `6` reputation, but on Stack Overflow на русском I have `88` reputation. I want to vote for good questions, but I can not do it, because I have not 15 reputation.

How can I take reputation from Stack Overflow на русском?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can not. Reputation can't be transferred between different sites.

*However*, you can earn 200 rep on either site and get 100 rep on every other site as an [association bonus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/). This will get you past the [lowest privilege levels](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) on each new site. This will allow you to upvote and comment (among others), but not down vote until you've participated a bit on each individual site.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to transfer reputation between sites. The one exception is the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/223467) - once you reach 200 points in one account, all your accounts, including new ones you open after receiving this bonus, will gain an additional 100 points.